# Where to save AWS Credentials file when using shared hosting?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I'm using Amazon's AWS PHP SDK and I installed composer on the following directory 'public_html/composer'. I am currently using shared hosting. However, I have access to the root.

When I tried using [AWS's sample code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-sdk-php.html) I'm getting the following errors in my error_log:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Aws\Exception\CredentialsException: Cannot read credentials from /.aws/credentials in /home2/maltaboo/public_html/composer/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Credentials/CredentialProvider.php:691 Stack trace: #0 /home2/maltaboo/public_html/composer/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Credentials/CredentialProvider.php(424): Aws\Credentials\CredentialProvider::reject('Cannot read cre...') #1 /home2/maltaboo/public_html/composer/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Middleware.php(121): Aws\Credentials\CredentialProvider::Aws\Credentials\{closure}() #2 /home2/maltaboo/public_html/composer/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/RetryMiddleware.php(266): Aws\Middleware::Aws\{closure}(Object(Aws\Command), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request)) #3 /home2/maltaboo/public_html/composer/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Middleware.php(206): Aws\RetryMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Aws\Command), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request)) #4 /home2/maltaboo/public_html/composer/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/StreamRequestPayloadMiddleware.php(83): Aws\Middleware::Aws\{closure}(Ob in /home2/maltaboo/public_html/composer/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Credentials/CredentialProvider.php on line 691
```

I created my credentials files as per AWS tutorial:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = 123456789
aws_secret_access_key = abcdefghijklm
```

The documentation states that I must save it in this location: `~/.aws/credentials`

I tried many times to create the directory `.aws/credentials` however I get the same error. I tried also looking for the `.aws` file but I couldn't locate it except the one that I just created.

Given the above where should I place the credentials file? TIA

Comment: are u using windows/linux? And what error do you get while making directory

Comment: I'm using Linux. I get the same error as above that the credentials file cannot be located.

Comment: have you installed the aws sdk on your ubuntu machine. Those are OS supported,

Comment: Yes I already installed them.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue of `cannot read /.aws/credentials`

Mentioning my solution here for reference:

This solution is **tested in aws-php-sdk version 3.173**:

CredentialProvider.php uses `getenv('HOME')/.aws/credentials` path to load the credentials from the file.

In my case (linux shared hosting) it was empty.

So I set it to desired value using:

```
putenv("HOME=/absolute/path/to/folder/containing/.aws/folder")
```